# Vue-router returns undefined when used in component library

Tags: vuejs3, vue-router, vite

I've been grappling with this issue for a few weeks now and I don't seem to find any information anywhere, besides some dead ends on stackoverflow and vue-router's own github issues.

I am attempting to develop an init function for my vue-router inside a vite based component library and then consuming it in a client app using npm link for local development, the problem persists even with published versions of the library. The method initiating the router works well enough by itself, returning the router to be used in the consuming app, the issue arises when I attempt to call useRoute or useRouter inside one of the client app's components and receive undefined.

I also get a "injection "Symbol(router)" not found" warning on my console. (Which led me to suspect instance duplication initially)

Vite config rollupOptions

```
rollupOptions: {
        external: ["vue", "vue-router"],
      },
```

The offending function
​

```
import "vue-router";
import { RouteRecordRaw, createRouter, createWebHashHistory } from "vue-router";

declare module "vue-router" {
  interface RouteMeta {
    step: number;
    displayStep: number;
    displayTotalSteps: number;
    fields: string[];
  }

  interface Router {
    replaceRoutes: (newRoutesName: string) => void;
    nextStep: () => void;
    previousStep: () => void;
    skipStep: (skipNr: number) => void;
  }
}

export const createRouterInstance = (options: {
  sessionRoutesToken: string;
  routeGetter: (routes: string | null) => RouteRecordRaw[];
}) => {
  const router = createRouter({
    history: createWebHashHistory(),
    routes: options.routeGetter(
      window.sessionStorage.getItem(options.sessionRoutesToken)
    ),
    scrollBehavior: () => ({ top: 0 }),
  });

  router.beforeEach((to, from) => {
    to.meta.animation =
      from.meta?.step < to.meta?.step ? "slide-right" : "slide-left";
  });

  router.replaceRoutes = ...

  router.nextStep = ...

  router.previousStep = ...

  router.skipStep = ...

  return router;
};
```

I've suspected duped instances and configured my component library's instance as external to no avail.

Answer (score 0):

I got a light in my mind, reading last line of your question: `I've suspected duped instances and configured my component library's instance as external to no avail.`

In my case, I solved the problem adding `configureWebpack` option in `vue.config.js` of my project which uses the problematic library which also uses `vue-router` inside.

```
const { defineConfig } = require("@vue/cli-service");
const path = require('path');

module.exports = defineConfig({
  transpileDependencies: true,
  filenameHashing: false,
  configureWebpack: {
    resolve: {
      symlinks: false,
      alias: {
        vue: path.resolve('./node_modules/vue'),
        'vue-router': path.resolve('./node_modules/vue-router') // <--- here
      }
    }
  }
});
```